# Docker - Cannot connect to the Docker Daemon to rm containers

Tags: docker, elastic-stack

Playing with ELK and docker, I needed to restart every services.

`docker ps` told me that I haven't any containers up.

`docker run -it --rm [...] --name es elasticsearch` -> `Error response from daemon. The name "es" is already use by container [...]`

So I try to remove all container :

`docker ps -a -q | xargs docker rm` -> `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?`

The container is not up but still here.

Of course I can simply change my container's name but it's not right. That mean I have container running. Even if I restart my server.

Any idea ?

Comment: To remove all: `docker rm $(docker stop $(docker pq -qa))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you stop your container it's not getting removed by default, unless you're providing `--rm` flag. So, it could be so, like you have started and stopped some container with `es` name before and it's stopped now. But it's not possible to create a new container with the existing name, even if the existing one is not running. Try to use a `-a` flag to show all containers you have as:

```
docker ps -a
```

If you have some with the name `es`, just remove it manually with:

```
docker rm es
```

You also able to provide `-f` flag, to force removing the `es` container even if it's running.

Comment: I added the --rm flag as you can see in my original post. That's why I got confused.

Answer (score 1):

docker rm es should do the trick. Furthermore, if you want to remove a running container, you can add the -f parameter(docker rm -f 'container_name')